# I'm having trouble with strcmp. for some reason it detected the wrong word and still continued on with the code

Tags: c, strcmp

This is my code here and for some reason the float detected with the string compare is weird
The data i have rn for my metal is currently "Lea". As you can see from the string compare when detected lea will use f2 as the float but for some reason when it detected "Lea" it used the first comparison with "CoP"

```
// variables declaration
char cusdate [50], first[50], last [50], ic[50], ic2[50], address[100], contact[50], email[100];
char dailydate [50], unitname2 [50], metal[50],mass[50];
char ext [10]= ".txt";
char fullname[100] = "C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Accounts\\";
char CoP[10]="CoP",Lea[10]="Lea",Tin[10]="Tin",Znc[10]="Znc",Ore[10]="Ore",Alu[10]="Alu",Aly[10]="Aly",Nic[10]="Nic";
float Originalinvestment,i;
double funds;
FILE *ptr1;
FILE *ptr2;
char investdate [20], investname [20], contractname [20], subchoice, YNchoice, newexitchoice, line[500];
double investkg, investamount, kgprice, newprice, amountinvested2, totalunit2, total2;
float f1 = 0.01, f2 = 0.02, f3 = 0.01, f4 = 0.03, f5 = 0.01, f6 = 0.04, f7 = 0.02, f8 = 0.03, service2;
int fundselect2,count=1;
float service;
// to get latest reading time of the file
struct stat filestat;
// prompt user for input
system ("cls");
printf ("1.2 Existing Customer Portfolio\n");
printf ("-----------------------------\n\n");
printf ("Enter customer IC No : ");
fflush(stdin);
gets (ic);
// combine the strings together to get the full file path name
strcat (fullname, ic);
strcat (fullname, ext);
// open file
ptr1 = fopen (fullname , "r");
ptr2 = fopen ("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt", "r");
stat (fullname, &filestat);
if (ptr1 == NULL) // to ensure the file exist
{
printf ("File does not exist...Please try again.\n");
printf ("The program will now be terminated\n");
exit (1);
}
if (ptr2 == NULL) // to ensure the file exist
{
printf ("File does not exist...Please try again.\n");
printf ("The program will now be terminated\n");

exit (1);
}
// get data from the file
fgets (first, 100, ptr1);
puts(cusdate);

printf("\tFUTURE CONTRAT PORTFOLIO (YOUR WEALTH)");
printf("\n******************************************************************************************************************************************************");
printf("\nMetal Commodity\t\tKG held\t\tCurrency\t\tContract Price\t\tCurrent VAlue(CV)\t Profit/(Loss)(RM)");
printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
count=1;
        ptr1 = fopen(fullname,"r");
        while (fgets(metal, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {   
            if (count == 7)
            {   
            printf("\n%s", metal);
            fclose(ptr1);

            }   
            else
            {   
                count++;
            }   
        }   
        fclose(ptr1);
```

This part of the code is where I'm having trouble with. The function that i was going for was to have it detect what type of metal was inputted and insert the declared float to it. but for somereason my Lea was detected as CoP and used f1 instead of the intended f2

```
    if(strcmp(metal,CoP)==0)
    {
        service=f1;
    }
    else if(strcmp(metal,Lea)==0)
    {
        service=f2;
    }
    else if(strcmp(metal,Tin)==0)
    {
        service=f3;
    }
    else if(strcmp(metal,Znc)==0)
    {
        service=f4;
    }
    else if(strcmp(metal,Ore)==0)
    {
        service=f5;
    }
    else if(strcmp(metal,Alu)==0)
    {
        service=f6;
    }
    else if(strcmp(metal,Aly)==0)
    {
        service=f7;
    }
    else if(strcmp(metal,Nic)==0)
    {
        service=f8;
    }
    
        count=1;
        ptr1 = fopen(fullname,"r");
        while (fgets(mass, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {   
            if (count == 8)
            {   
            
            printf("\e[A\t\t\t%s", mass);
            fclose(ptr1);

            }   
            else
            {   
                count++;
            }   
        }   
        fclose(ptr1);
        
        count=1;
        ptr1 = fopen(fullname,"r");
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {   
            if (count == 9)
            {   
            Originalinvestment = atoi(mass)*atof(line);
            
            printf("\n\n%.2f\n\n",service);
            printf("\e[A\t\t\t\t\tMYR\t\t\t%.2f", Originalinvestment);
            fclose(ptr1);

            }   
            else
            {   
                count++;
            }   
        }   
        fclose(ptr1);
        if(strcmp(metal,CoP)==1)
        {
            count=1;
            ptr1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
            {   
                if (count == 1)
                {   
                
                printf("\t\t\t%s", line);
                fclose(ptr1);

                }   
                else
                {   
                    count++;
                }   
            }   
            fclose(ptr1);
        }
            else if(strcmp(metal,Lea)==1)
            {
            count=1;
            ptr1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
            {   
                if (count == 2)
                {   
                
                printf("\t\t\t%s", line);
                fclose(ptr1);

                }   
                else
                {   
                    count++;
                }   
            }   
            fclose(ptr1);
            }
            else if(strcmp(metal,Tin)==1)
            {
            count=1;
            ptr1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
            {   
                if (count == 3)
                {   
                
                printf("\t\t\t%s", line);
                fclose(ptr1);

                }   
                else
                {   
                    count++;
                }   
            }   
            fclose(ptr1);
            }
            else if(strcmp(metal,Znc)==1)
            {
            count=1;
            ptr1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
            {   
                if (count == 4)
                {   
                
                printf("\t\t\t%s", line);
                fclose(ptr1);

                }   
                else
                {   
                    count++;
                }   
            }   
            fclose(ptr1);
            }
            else if(strcmp(metal,Ore)==1)
            {
            count=1;
            ptr1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
            {   
                if (count == 5)
                {   
                
                printf("\t\t\t%s", line);
                fclose(ptr1);

                }   
                else
                {   
                    count++;
                }   
            }   
            fclose(ptr1);
            }
            else if(strcmp(metal,Alu)==1)
            {
            count=1;
            ptr1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
            {   
                if (count == 6)
                {   
                
                printf("\t\t\t%s", line);
                fclose(ptr1);

                }   
                else
                {   
                    count++;
                }   
            }   
            fclose(ptr1);
            }
            else if(strcmp(metal,Aly)==1)
            {
            count=1;
            ptr1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
            {   
                if (count == 7)
                {   
                
                printf("\t\t\t%s", line);
                fclose(ptr1);

                }   
                else
                {   
                    count++;
                }   
            }   
            fclose(ptr1);
            }
        
        else if(strcmp(metal,Nic)==1)
            {
            count=1;
            ptr1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Industrial_Metal.txt","r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr1) != NULL) /* read a line */
            {   
                if (count == 8)
                {   
                
                printf("\t\t\t%s", line);
                fclose(ptr1);

                }   
                else
                {   
                    count++;
                }   
            }   
            fclose(ptr1);
            }
            
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa7tT.png)
The Lea there is printed with the char metal and underneath the word Lea should be 0.02 if it detects it but for some reason it just doesn't detect it

Comment: strcmp returns 0 when it matches, not 1. It will return < 0 of the first string is smaller and > if the first string is larger than the second. Zero if the two strings are equal. If you compare “Lea” with “CoP” you get 1. That is why it picks f1.

Comment: i see so what do you think i should do to fix this error? i tried doing all 0 but that also didn't work

Comment: If strcmp returns 0 when the two strings are equal, and you want to check if two strings are equal, I should think the answer would be obvious. Use if (strcmp(a,b) == 0)

Comment: yeah i tried that but it ended up not detecting any of the things and just came out as 0.00

Comment: If none of the strings match, then metal isn’t one of them. That isn’t strcmp’s fault, though. It will tell you if one matches by returning zero. Are you sure that metal is one of the expected strings? You read it from a file, so I can’t check. There isn’t extra white space around it, for example?

Comment: i'm pretty sure that it is cause have another line of code at the bottom that also uses   else if(strcmp(metal,Nic)==1) this exact same command but that part works

Comment: strcmp does not return 1 if the two strings differ, no. Regardless of what your code does. However, I notice you read metal with fgets. That means it has the newline in it, which the characters you compare with do not. Since “abc\n” is larger than “abc”, strcmp(“abc\n”,”abc”) == 1, so that might be fooling your code. The strings are not the same, though.

Comment: Another thing: when you read in metal, you allow the function to write sizeof line characters, which is 100. But metal is only 50. You have a potential overflow there.

Comment: thanks i'll fix that, but weirdly enough it still doesn't work

Comment: Then there is more than one bug. I suggest that you first make sure that strcmp works the way i claim or the way you think. Both can’t be right. Then I suggest that you write a smaller program that just prints the metal variable you read in, because I suspect it isn’t what you think it is. If you print it, make sure that you can see if it contains spaces; put it in quotes. Those two sanity checks will be a good way to start debugging.

Comment: ok so i tried it in a smaller code like you said and it works exactly like you said i tried looking through the big code but i still don't see any red flags that might make it not work

Comment: Don’t just read the code. Test your assumptions everywhere. If it doesn’t work and you can’t spot where, then you need to look closer.

Comment: ok i got it to work now for some reason after i changed it to else if(strncmp(metal,Lea,2)==0) it suddenly works perfectly

Comment: That is only checking the first two characters so this is a dangerous approach. Don’t cargo cult program.

Comment: ok then i'll look closer